# How can I cd into directories in a for loop when the directories have spaces?

Tags: loops, for-loop

Here is a simple for loop where aaa.txt is a list of directories.

```
#!/bin/bash

for variable in $(cat aaa.txt)
do
cd $variable && mv *.avi /home/xxx/Downloads/Marple && rm -rf $variable
done
```

But each directory is something like:

Agatha Christies Marple 1x02 - The Murder At The Vicarage

The spaces prevent the $variable from working. I've tried "$variable" but that doesn't work.

So I changed aaa.txt to

```
Agatha\ Christies\ Marple\ 1x02\ -\ The\ Murder\ At\ The\ Vicarage
```

That didn't work either.

How can I 'cd' into directories with spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r dir; do
    cd "$dir" && mv *.avi /home/xxx/Downloads/Marple && rm -rf "$variable"
done < aaa.txt
```

to prevent *work splitting*.

Check [How can I read a file line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Thanks. That worked well after I removed the \ from the aaa.txt list of directories. So IFS= I imagine is the Initial File Separator - which is null? And then read -r dir takes every entry from the dir variable (which is the list of directories in aaa.txt) and performs the next line on it. Is that correct?

Comment: `IFS` is _input_ separator which is null, yes. `read -r` store safely the current line in the variable `dir`. This loop read files _line by line_. All is explained in depth in the link I provided